# Ansible edit array of json objects in place or sort for different values when undefined

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list of json objects, that looks something like this

```
[
  {
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "count": 11,
    "eventTime": null,
    "firstTimestamp": "2020-10-20T16:17:08Z",
    "lastTimestamp": "2020-10-20T16:30:38Z",
    "involvedObject": {
        "apiVersion": "v1"
    },
    "kind": "Event"
  },
  {
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "count": 11,
    "eventTime": "2020-10-20T16:17:10.182317Z"
    "firstTimestamp": null,
    "lastTimestamp": null,
    "involvedObject": {
        "apiVersion": "v1"
    },
    "kind": "Event"
  }
]
```

I would like to be able to sort this array by `lastTimestamp` and if `lastTimestamp` was not defined by `eventTime`. Since this does not work with `sort` - to my knowledge at least, I was thinking about manipulating the array, setting `lastTimestamp` to `eventTime` when `lastTimestamp` is null.

Since I am new to Ansible, I am not sure how to manipulate a list in place in order to archive my goal. Or is there even a way to sort by two attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sumarize briefly, you don't edit in place in ansible. You manipulate the data to create a new data structure adapted to your need

In your specific case, I don't think there is any other way than using `set_fact` and looping over your original data to examine each item (i.e. I don't see a solution by simply applying a series of filters on the original data).

The new items in your new list will be obtained by combining the original dict with a dict containing the correct date or an empty one to keep the current date.

Here is a quick example playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Process date and sort
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Your original data as json on a single line to shorten display
    api_events: [{"apiVersion": "v1", "count": 11, "eventTime": null, "firstTimestamp": "2020-10-20T16:17:08Z", "lastTimestamp": "2020-10-20T16:30:38Z", "involvedObject": {"apiVersion": "v1"}, "kind": "Event"}, {"apiVersion": "v1", "count": 11, "eventTime": "2020-10-20T16:17:10.182317Z", "firstTimestamp": null, "lastTimestamp": null, "involvedObject": {"apiVersion": "v1"}, "kind": "Event"}]

  tasks:
    - name: Process API events to determine time we will use
      vars:
        new_timestamp: "{{ item.firstTimestamp | ternary({}, {'firstTimestamp': item.eventTime}) }}"
        current_event: "{{ item | combine(new_timestamp) }}"
      set_fact:
        processed_api_events: "{{ processed_api_events | default([]) + [current_event] }}"
      loop: "{{ api_events }}"

    - name: Show result sorted
      debug:
        msg: "{{ processed_api_events | sort(attribute='firstTimestamp') }}"
```

which gives:

```
PLAY [Process date and sort] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Process API events to determine time we will use] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'apiVersion': 'v1', 'count': 11, 'eventTime': None, 'firstTimestamp': '2020-10-20T16:17:08Z', 'lastTimestamp': '2020-10-20T16:30:38Z', 'involvedObject': {'apiVersion': 'v1'}, 'kind': 'Event'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'apiVersion': 'v1', 'count': 11, 'eventTime': '2020-10-20T16:17:10.182317Z', 'firstTimestamp': None, 'lastTimestamp': None, 'involvedObject': {'apiVersion': 'v1'}, 'kind': 'Event'})

TASK [Show result sorted] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "count": 11,
            "eventTime": null,
            "firstTimestamp": "2020-10-20T16:17:08Z",
            "involvedObject": {
                "apiVersion": "v1"
            },
            "kind": "Event",
            "lastTimestamp": "2020-10-20T16:30:38Z"
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "count": 11,
            "eventTime": "2020-10-20T16:17:10.182317Z",
            "firstTimestamp": "2020-10-20T16:17:10.182317Z",
            "involvedObject": {
                "apiVersion": "v1"
            },
            "kind": "Event",
            "lastTimestamp": null
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```